# Honey shader in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

Trying to make honey material. I think there is some manipulation with nodes I need to do to get results but I have not enough experienced in that.
Can you please help me simulate honey consistency and color?

[image]

To(kind of):
[image]

Comment: The main difference between the images is due to the lighting (same thing for the preview). Try to work on both side: shaders&lighting.

Comment: Yea, for a shader to look real you need context. The shader is not just the sum of all nodes, lighting, reflections and environment have a big influence in its appearance. Make a bottle around it, get a background going, add something to reflect.

Comment: some kind of scattering (subsurface or volume scattering) would help as well.

Comment: I'd suggest [starting with an HDR](https://hdrihaven.com/bundle.php?b=free_bundle). This does (at least) two things for you at the same time: gives you realistic lighting and something to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will get you started... As others have said lighting is very important. This example uses Cycles to render and incorporates an HDRi for the overall lighting. An emission plane for an additional reflection (Camera Left) and a point light to brighten up the "Honey".

[image: Honey Material]

[image: Glass Material]

[image: Render]

Answer (score -1):

If you need more control over the color of the honey and being able to adjust it with different colors and shades of color, you can use a color ramp. You can also replace the emission shader with a glossy and translucent shader by adding both to a mix shader before connecting to the Material Output.

[image]

[image]