# How to make a material with thickness dependant transparency

Tags: materials, transparency

I want to recreate the material of the icing on these donuts; transparent at thinner areas and opaque at thicker areas. I fiddled around with transmission, alpha, and volume absorption, but couldn't recreate it. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you done any reserch? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72495/create-a-gradient-effect-like-for-coffee/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36183/get-object-width-in-cycles-as-value/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76081/honey-shader-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77215/suspended-particles-inside-a-material-procedural

Comment: are you using Cycles or Eevee?

Comment: Im using cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the effect i want via principled volume, but i was unable to output a white color via that node. Bumping up the volume bounces under 'Render Properties'> 'Light bounces' > 'Volume' fixed the color issue as far as i can tell

Answer (score 4):

Does the transparency actually have to match the depth, or are you just going for the appearance of it? If you just want the look, you can simulate the depth (bumps and valleys) of the icing using a Noise Texture as the basis for a Bump (Normal) map, and then use that same Noise texture as the basis for the "translucency mix". That way, the simulated "low (thin) areas" have a higher degree of transparency, making the icing appear thinner in those areas, and vice-versa:

[image: Icing]

Comment: The transparancy has to match the depth, im looking for an effect similar to if not the one volume absorptions produces, problem is that node butchers my colours, and idk how to get the same effect on the donut.

Comment: Omar, if you use this option, you can still match the depth! Just add a displace modifier to the icing mesh, create a new texture, go to texture settings, and add a noise texture from the internet. Then, in Chris' answer's node setup, use the EXACT same noise texture as a image node instead of his Noise Texture. This way, the noise texture will match the thickness/displacement!

Answer (score 1):

In Cycles you can plug a *Principled Volume* into the *Volume* input of the *Output*, set its *Density* to the good value, also mix a *Transparent* node with a *Glossy*. You can also add a bit of fake noise on the surface with a *Bump* plugged into the *Glossy*:

[image]

Comment: Density nodes consistently ruin the color. the object becomes grey instead of white